# Powershell foreach in pssession

Tags: powershell

I am installing Office 2010 with parameter, I created a `PSSession` with admin rights to deploy my scripts, but I have a problem with multiple user.

I can't use invoke because installation does not start.

Is there another method to deploy this script to multiple computers?

```
CLS
Start-Job -Name Job1 -ScriptBlock { 
$domainuser = "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\administrator"
$domainpassword = 'Credential' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$domaincredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($domainuser, $domainpassword)
$ip = "192.168.10.75" 

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -Credential $domaincredentials }
Wait-Job -Name Job1
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Verb runAs
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\temp\32 Bit\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/adminfile Office2010.MSP"
```

Answer (score 0):

To just run `setup.exe` (as Administrator), on the remote computer:

```
$domainuser = "$env:USERDNSDOMAIN\administrator"
$domainpassword = 'Credential' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$domaincredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($domainuser, $domainpassword)
$ip = "192.168.10.75" 

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -Credential $domaincredentials
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\temp\32 Bit\setup.exe" -ArgumentList '/adminfile "C:\temp\32 Bit\Office2010.MSP"' -Verb runAs -Wait
Exit-PSSession
```

I've assumed the MSP is in the same folder as setup, so I've included the full path to the MSP file... and used double quotes around it due to the space folder name.